# d3: drawing elements correctly but not adding new data to the dom

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, d3.js

Using d3, I have some simple markup like this:

```
<div id="my-log"></div>
```

I have an object that uses d3 to render. I've got a number of these that draw charts and graphs, but this one just prints a log.

Here's the code:

```
class Log

  # Run on DOM Ready
  constructor: (selector,data) ->
    @s = selector
    @data = data || this.mockData()
    this.setup()
    this.draw()

  # Append a message onto the end of the log. Optionally shift the first point off.
  pushData: (message, shift = false) ->
    @data.push message
    @data.shift() if shift
    this.update()

  mockData: ->
    [{
      sender: 'tester',
      message: 'foo bar baz'
    }]

  template: (data) ->
    """
    <div class="sender">#{data.sender}</div>
    <div class="message">#{data.message}</div>
    """

  setup: ->
    @container = d3.select(@s).append('ul').attr('class','log')

  draw: ->
    @container.selectAll('li')
      .data( @data )
    .enter().append('li')
      .html (d) => this.template(d)

  update: ->
    @container.selectAll('li')
      .data( @data )
      .html (d) => this.template(d)
```

To initialize this I call it like so:

```
jQuery ->
  myLog = new Log 'div#my-log'
```

This correctly selects the div and renders the message into it.

However, if I try to add log messages in the console:

```
log.pushData({sender:'test', message:'foo'});
```

... this does not get rendered to the DOM. If I call `log.data` in the console I see the data is there, it just didn't make it to the DOM.

I haven't been able to spot my mistake, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `.enter` in update

```
update: ->
    @container.selectAll('li')
      .data( @data )
    .enter().append('li')
      .html (d) => this.template(d)
```

as a note you should also add a `.exit` to update